# p4 client returns with credential mismatch error

Tags: perforce, perforce-client-spec

When I use `p4 client` I get a "credential mismatch" error:

```
~$ p4 client
credential mismatch: P4USER specified abadescu, p4filter command line specified idror
Partner exited unexpectedly.
Perforce client error:
    Partner exited unexpectedly.
~$ echo $P4USER

~$ P4USER=idror p4 client
credential mismatch: P4USER specified abadescu, p4filter command line specified idror
Partner exited unexpectedly.
Perforce client error:
    Partner exited unexpectedly.
```

using `p4 -u idror client` does open the editor, but after I save the modifications don't seem to affect `p4 sync` or `p4 -u idror sync`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That "credential mismatch" message is not a Perforce message, but rather is coming from some locally-customized configuration at your site.

Perhaps you have a trigger, for example a 'form-out' trigger.

Your trigger might use a locally-developed program named 'p4filter'.

Or perhaps you have a client-side wrapper for the 'p4' command, which might use a locally-developed client-side program named 'p4filter'.

You should ask the Perforce administrator at your site for help with resolving this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove temporary the `P4CONFIG` from environment variables.
And most of all you need to have loaded ssh-agent that has key for user `abadescu`. If you don't use ssh keys to authenticate remove them from chain

So:

```
$ export -n P4CONFIG
$ ssh-add -D # if needed
```

And then set `client`, `user`, `port` in the p4 command like:

```
$ p4 -c client_name -u abadescu -p port_string_here
```